# How can I get a specific value from the json_decode?

Tags: php, json

```
$data = json_decode ($response, true);

print_r($data);

Array (
      ['statusCode'] => 200 ,
      ['body'] => '{ "userid": [admin", "test"] }'
);
```

I wanna get a print here.

```
print_r($data['userid'][0]);
```

There's no result.

How can I get a specific value from the `json_decode`?

Comment: Please show the response rather than the data

Comment: that ```body``` part, it seems it's a string that is json. so change it to array again by ```json_decode```

Comment: echo '<xmp>$response = ', var_export($temp ,1), ';</xmp>'; than $response = array (
  'statusCode' => 200,
  'body' => '{
"userid": [
"admin",
"test"
]
}',
);

Answer (score -1):

The body seems to be a json
So you need to do `json_decode ($data [body])`

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'body' in /www/json.php on line 18